# Emberjs redirecting after login from previous url

Tags: ember.js

I have an app that you can only get in if you are log in. I would like to do a redirection after the user is log but, only if he tried to access a page from the website.

Example :

The user receive this link in his email :

`http://mywebsite.com/#/enquiry/1`

When he click on it, it will be redirected on the login form because he's not log in. But just after the log in is good he is automatically redirected to this last link.

I already have the redirect from anywhere to the login form if he is not log but I have no idea how to save the URL and go back there again..

I used the redirection like this :

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        if ( not log in ) {
            // TransitionToLogin
        }
    }
});
```

Someone know how I can achieve this ?

Thank you !

Comment: This specific case is documented at the Ember Guide (STORING AND RETRYING A TRANSITION)http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/

Comment: Well thank you for this, it is working, but I have one problem with that. The url is `/enquiry/undefined` instead of `/enquiry/1`, and I don't know how to fix that... otherwise its redirecting me well.

Comment: This is another issue on how you setup your route definition with dynamic segment and implement your route.model method. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/  If you need help, try to reproduce your case with http://emberjs.jsbin.com/, so other can help you in an easier way.

Answer (score 4):

#### Quick explanation if you're familiar with ember and routing:

You can do this by using the `beforeModel(transition) { ... }` hook on the route to see if you are logged in. If you're not logged in, stash the transition variable somewhere, temporarily transition to your login route, then when you've successfully authenticated, `.retry()` the stored previous transition.

Make sure bullet proof this, as your auth code is pretty "global" on your site. Handle the case where the user goes straight to login, and thus the login route doesn't have a stashed transition available. Also handle weird cases, like if they go to the login page twice, by cleaning up your temp storage for the transition before you call `.retry()` on it.

#### An alternative, use Torii:

If you don't want to build this yourself and have to copy this code on all your protected routes, then [the Torii authentication library](https://github.com/Vestorly/torii) has support for this already, using [their protected route mapping function](https://github.com/Vestorly/torii#router-dsl). Once you've got your session and provider set up, you simply use the `this.authenticatedRoute('my-protected-route');` route mapping function instead of the normal `this.route('my-route');` that you've already been using.

The Torii docs are a little challenging to get through, but once you've figured them out, that library is very useful in getting up and running quickly with multiple authentication mechanisms. It is very little work to start supporting both an email/password and a Facebook login, for example. I recommend checking it out.

#### Non-Torii code sample:

If you just want to use vanilla Ember, and implement this yourself, I'd provide a code sample for your example, but as ppcano mentioned in comments, [this is covered in the documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/#toc_storing-and-retrying-a-transition). Here's the corresponding text from the docs. It covers everything I mentioned above in the quick explanation.

> #### STORING AND RETRYING A TRANSITION
>
> Aborted transitions can be retried at a later time. A common use case for this is having an authenticated route redirect the user to a login page, and then redirecting them back to the authenticated route once they've logged in.

---

```
// app/routes/some-authenticated.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel(transition) {
    if (!this.controllerFor('auth').get('userIsLoggedIn')) {
      var loginController = this.controllerFor('login');
      loginController.set('previousTransition', transition);
      this.transitionTo('login');
    }
  }
});
```

---

```
// app/controllers/login.js

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    login() {
      // Log the user in, then reattempt previous transition if it exists.
      var previousTransition = this.get('previousTransition');
      if (previousTransition) {
        this.set('previousTransition', null);
        previousTransition.retry();
      } else {
        // Default back to homepage
        this.transitionToRoute('index');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth), then take a look at [AuthenticatedRouteMixin](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/AuthenticatedRouteMixin.html), it forces authentication before transitioning to the target route.

It also takes care of redirecting to the previous URL after authentication.

If you are using this mixin and also overriding sessionAuthenticated(), then make sure you have `this._super(...arguments);` in sessionAuthenticated() to preserve the redirection logic.